# Can't add `__init_subclass__` after class has been created

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have a class decorator that is supposed to add an `__init_subclass__` method, but when I do:

```py
class A:
 def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
  print(cls)

class B:
 pass

def p(cls, **kwargs):
 print(cls)

B.__init_subclass__ = p

class C(A):
 pass

# Prints class C

class D(B):
 pass

# TypeError: p() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

The difference seems to be that `A.__init_subclass__` is a bound method of class A, while p is just a function. But how does the method of class A get bound to the new subclass which doesn't even exist before the class context has been exited? Binding p to B using `B.__init_subclass__.__get__(B)` causes the `cls` argument to be equal to B itself, rather than to the new subclass as is the case with the magically bound `A.__init_subclass__`

How can I perform the same magic that Python does myself after the class has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init_subclass__` needs to be a classmethod. `type.__new__` automatically makes `__init_subclass__` a classmethod if it's a regular function at class creation time, but if you add `__init_subclass__` later, that doesn't happen.

If you add `__init_subclass__` after creating a class, you need to add the `@classmethod` decorator yourself.

Comment: Interesting and correct! Could you explain in your answer what the difference is between `A.__init_subclass__ = A.__init_subclass__.__get__(A)` and the `classmethod` decorator? I always assumed that the classmethod decorator binds the class the method is defined in. How does it bind the subclass? I'm going to assume that the classmethod decorator returns some object with a special descriptor protocol?